# Why does memorylessness propetry of geometric distribution imply $\mathcal{L}_{P(\cdot\lvert X \geq k+1)}(X-k)=\mathcal{L}_{P}(X)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

We use the notation $\mathcal{L}_{P}(X)$ to denote the probability distribution $P\circ X^{-1}$.

I know the memorylessness propetry of the geometric distribution as the following:

$P(X\geq t+s\lvert X \geq t)=P(X\geq s)$ where $t,s \in \mathbb N_{0}$ $(1)$

but recently I saw the following assumption made based on the geometric distribution of $X$:

$\mathcal{L}_{P(\cdot\lvert X \geq k+1)}(X-k)=\mathcal{L}_{P}(X)$ for any $k \in \mathbb N$ $(2)$

I am having difficulty proving why $(1)$ implies $(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

$(2)$ means that the distribution of $X$ (with respect to $\mathbb P$) is the same as distribution of random variable $X-k$ with respect to $\mathbb P(\cdot | X \ge k+1)$ for any $ k \in \mathbb N$. Let's check, since $X$ has geometric distribution, it is enough to check for $m \in \mathbb N$ if $\mathbb P(X \ge m) =^? \mathbb P( (X-k) \ge m | X \ge k+1) = \mathbb P(X \ge m+k | X \ge k+1)$. Okay, now we encounter a problem concerning the different definitions of Geometric distributions (sometimes it is defined as $\mathbb P(Y=k) = (1-p)^k p$ for $k \in \{0,1,..\}$ and sometimes $\mathbb P(Y=k) = (1-p)^{k-1}p$ for $ k \in \{1,...\}$). So in your definition of geometric distribution, when $(1)$ holds then $\mathcal L_{\mathbb P(\cdot | X \ge k)}(X-k) = \mathcal L_{\mathbb P}(X)$ holds and everything goes as before:

$\mathbb P(X \ge m) = ^? = \mathbb P( X-k \ge m | X \ge k) = \mathbb P(X \ge m+k | X \ge k) = \mathbb P(X \ge m)$ by $(1)$, so it's true.